# Setting state on multiple variables at once from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and React.  I've successfully retrieved user data from firebase with the following code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  if(firebaseUser) {
    const dbRoot = firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(firebaseUser.uid);
    const name = dbRoot.child('name');
    const bio = dbRoot.child('bio');

    name.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        name: snap.val()
      });
    });

    bio.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        bio: snap.val()
      });
    });

  } else {
    console.log("not logged in");
  }
});
```

}

This works, but I'm looking for a better way to setState on all the values (name, bio, etc) without having to create multiple setState blocks like from above, and I haven't discovered it yet. I have a lot of data to get from the user, so that code will get more cumbersome.  I'd like to do something like:

```
this.setState({
   name: snap.name.val(),
   bio: snap.bio.val(),
   email: snap.email.val()
});
```

Or whatever the best protocol is. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have get the children 'name' and 'bio' separately from dbRoot:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  if(firebaseUser) {
    const dbRoot = firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(firebaseUser.uid);

    dbRoot.on('value', snap => {
      const user = snap.val(); // snap is a child of 'users'
      this.setState({
        name: user.name,
        bio: user.bio,
        email: user.email
      });
    });

  } else {
    console.log("not logged in");
  }
});
```

Comment: Yea, perfect, exactly what I was looking to do, and it works.  Thank you!